# sas ods columns - make "journal style" document

Tags: sas, sas-ods

I am trying to get some datasets printed to a PDF. Can anyone tell me how I can fit the last 4 `proc print`statements into a 2 x 2 on a single page, while leaving the first one on it's own page (as it is now)?

```
title;

options nodate nonumber nocenter orientation=portrait spool;

ods pdf file="I:\ASR\201410\bio.pdf" color=yes style=fancyprinter;

ods pdf startpage=NEVER;

ods escapechar='';

ods pdf text='S={just=CENTER preimage="I:/asr/logo.png" posttext=""';

ods pdf text= "S={just=c font_weight=bold font_size=12pt font_face=Arial}Fall 2013 - Annual Statistical Report";

ods pdf text= "S={just=c font_weight=bold font_size=12pt font_face=Arial}Department of Biology";

proc print data=IntApps_AY_cnt_p noobs; TITLE "Applications"; run;

ods pdf startpage=now;

proc print data=enroll_cnts_np noobs; TITLE "New Student Enrollment"; run;

ods pdf startpage=now;

proc print data=enroll_cnts_p noobs; TITLE "Total Enrollment"; run;

ods pdf startpage=now;

proc print data=TuitionScholarships_cnt_p noobs; TITLE "Stipends"; run;

ods pdf startpage=now;

proc print data=asr_degs_cnts_p noobs; TITLE "Academic Year 2012-2013 Awarded Degrees"; run;

ods layout end;

ods all close;
```

Thanks

JT

Comment: What are the measurements in dimensions of 2 x 2?

Comment: Nothing specific -- just as long as they're on the page.  These datasets printed aren't going to be that large in size and I am wanting to also include some text with them.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `columns=N` option in `ODS` to divide a page up into N columns. Try to manipulate the  number of columns to fit your data sets. Then use `startpage=no` and `startpage=now` to help you output your `print` statements in desired places.

SAS views each column as a new page, so you can exploit this to fit multiple `print` statement outputs onto one page.

Example using 2 columns:

```
options nodate nonumber;
data work.animals;
    input name $ weight;
    datalines;
    monkey 20
    shark 500
    lion 200
    wolf 120
    buffalo 400
    Parrot 10
    Lizard 30
    Human 150
    Whale 1000
    ;
run;

ods pdf file = 'C:\sasdata\animals2.pdf' columns = 2;

ods pdf startpage=no;
proc print data=work.animals; /* This print will be on a seperate page */
    title 'Seperate Paged Animals';
run;
ods pdf startpage=now;
ods pdf text="I want a little paragraph here that explains things about 
columns and startpages for putting this proc print statement on a 
seperate page. The other four statements will be outputed 
onto one page only divided into two columns.";

ods pdf startpage=now;
title;
proc print data=work.animals; /* 2nd print*/
run;

proc print data=work.animals; /*3rd print*/
run;

ods pdf startpage=now;

proc print data=work.animals; /*4th print*/
run;

proc print data=work.animals; /*5th print*/
run;

ods pdf close;
ods listing;
```

When we type `startpage=now`, it'll only go to a new column instead of a new page. Hence, the first `print` statement and the paragraph of text will be on a separate page. The last four `print` statements will be on one page.

Comment: Is there a way to make this so that the first page is just one column but the additional pages are 2 columns?  It seems that:

ods pdf file = 'C:\sasdata\animals2.pdf' columns = 2;

is going to be applied to the entire document, instead of just the 2nd page.  I have looked at some ODS region stuff, but I'm not really following and am not getting the results that I expect.

Comment: @user1624577 You can output the first print statement onto a separate pdf file with a different name without using columns (i.e. doing another `ods pdf file=`). And then merge the two pdf files together online using: http://foxyutils.com/mergepdf/ (you can download the file afterwards)

Comment: @user1624577 Did the merging of pdfs work or is it still causing some problems? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to use `ODS LAYOUT` to accomplish this.  If you have SAS 9.4, you might consider also learning `PROC ODSTABLE` or one of the other `PROC DOCUMENT` related procs (see [this doc page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odsug/66611/HTML/default/viewer.htm#odsugwhatsnew93.htm) for more details).  The `ODS LAYOUT` solution will work in SAS 9.3+, and might work in SAS 9.2, but I think it was very rusty back then.

The basic code would be something like

```
ods pdf file="c:\temp\blah.pdf";
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods pdf startpage=now;
ods layout start columns=2;
ods region;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods region;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods region;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods region;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods layout end;
ods pdf close;
```

You get 2 columns this way.  You would still have to control the rows by making things not too big; if that is an issue, you can control the height/width of the individual regions on the `ods region` statements (`ods region height=4in`), but that may or may not cause an issue in your results, since only some SAS outputs will scale the output to fit the space.

More information can be found in [You Did That Report in SAS®!?: The Power of the ODS PDF Destination](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/247-2011.pdf).